# how can I do a square root in python 2.7.13?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

How can I do a square root in python 2.7 ?
I tried do a simple calculator in python but i had a problem when i did the square root like it was written in google. can you explain me please how can I do it in the right way.

Comment: Show what you wrote and we can help with that but we cannot write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = 4
num_sqrt = num ** 0.5
print('The square root of %0.3f is %0.3f'%(num ,num_sqrt))
```

This works fine with me as it shows output of square root of number got from [python website](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/square-root)